# Find the longest path from root to leaf in a tree

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I have a [tree](https://www.iis.se/docs/DNS-bok-sid-14.jpg) (in the graph theory sense), such as the following example:

[image]

This is a directed tree with one starting node (the root) and many ending nodes (the leaves). Each of the edge has a length assigned to it.

My question is, how to find the longest path starting at the root and ending at any of the leaves? The brute-force approach is to check all the root-leaf paths and taking the one with maximal length, but I would prefer a more efficient algorithm if there is one.

Comment: [Related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11263/longest-path-in-an-undirected-tree-with-only-one-traversal).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ran G. gave hints towards an efficient algorithm, though perhaps he left out some details. Computing all root-leaf paths is indeed a little inefficient if you are doing work over and over again, for example, if you compute each path and then compute the length.

Perform the following recursive algorithm starting with `LongestPath(root)` will give
what you want. Essentially, it computes recursively the longest path for each subtree. At each node this requires building the new paths and returning the longest one.

```
 LongestPath(node)
   If node is a leaf, return (node,0) 
   If node is not a leaf:  
    For each edge (node,length,next):
       Let (p,l) = LongestPath(next)
       Let (path,len) = (p++[next], l + length)
    Return element (path,len) from previous step with largest value len
```

This is a combination if pseudo-code with some Haskell notation, so I hope it is comprehensible.